# c++ socket client keeps receiving something from Java server eventhough outputstream is closed

Tags: java, c++, sockets

I have server in java and a client in c++, and I have problem with the C++ client.
The client works like this:

1. Client waits for the Server to send the message "1"
2. When it does, the client calls the receive file method, and receives a file from the java server (everything works and the file is being received correctly).
3. The client closes the file, and goes back do the while loop and is supposed to wait for the server so send a new message.

The problem is that after the file has been received and it goes back, the client is just spamming out "Waiting for server for instructions". Here is the code:

```
    void getInstructions(SOCKET s)
{
    SOCKET connectSocket = s;
    // Get instructions from server
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Waiting for server for instructions" << endl;
        int rec;
        char buff[1024];
        //
        if ((rec = recv(connectSocket, buff, sizeof(buff)-1, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout << "Error at socket: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            cin.get();
            continue;
        }

        buff[rec] = 0;

        switch (buff[0])
        {
        case '1':
            receiveFile(connectSocket);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "THIS LINSE IS GETTING SPAMMED TOO" << endl;
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

The weird part is that the java server isn't sending anything else, but keeps the connection alive. And it doesn't seems to be a SOCKET ERROR because it isn't printing "error at socket" and the error. And in the Java server I ONLY close the outputstream NOT the socket.

What could possibly be wrong? If you request the code from the Java part or any other information, just leave a comment and I will fix it directly.

Comment: Are you sure `recv` is not returning a different code like `-1 `or `EOF`?

Comment: @PeterLawrey No I'm not sure, should I check for that? And what does it mean?

Comment: When the stream is closed, you should be getting an End-Of-File marker not an error. It is normal for a stream to be closed, not an error.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Ok, but why is it getting spammed out?

Comment: If you want to know, print the value of `rec` in your `default` in addition to the message, and tell us what you see.

Comment: And what if the connection is closed, i.e. when `recv` returns `0`? You don't check for that.

Comment: @PeterLawrey `SOCKET_ERROR` *is* defined to `-1`.

Comment: The recv tells you immediately there is no data, the stream is closed, but you ignore it and loop around and ask for more data.  The same thing would happen in Java BTW.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I will check for that brb

Comment: Also, if you get an error from `recv` you should really close the connection, there are very few cases where you can continue after an error.

Comment: @PeterLawrey the "rec" kepps prining 0 in the default when I added it

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I tried closeSocket(connectSocket) after the file was received, and then I got Socket error, and it printed error at socket. so i remved it again, and I saw now that recv returns "0".

Comment: @Johan that does sound odd. like you have a non blocking socket connection.  You need code to handle mis-aligned reads.  A TCP stream is a stream of bytes, not messages. A single read could read multiple messages or just one byte.

Comment: @Johan you shouldn't be reading the socket after you close it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey No I'm aware of that :P But I just wanted to see if the "if socket error" was printed, and it was. But whi is it returning zero, isn't that weird?

Comment: Just to make sure: on the Java side, you are talking about the output stream that comes from doing `getOutputStream()` from the socket object?

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes, OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream().

Comment: @RealSkeptic So "0" means that connection is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is where it goes wrong:

> And in the Java server I ONLY close the outputstream NOT the socket.

Actually, you are closing both. In the [JavaDoc for Socket.getOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getOutputStream%28%29), it says:

> Closing the returned `OutputStream` will close the associated socket.

So, in fact, the socket is closed properly. You actually no longer have a way to communicate with the client after closing the OutputStream.

I'll admit that I'm not a C++ expert, but I believe what happens on the C++ side is that when the socket is closed, the value returned is zero. This is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Windows, and [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html) for Linux: If the socket is closed on the other side, the returned value of `recv` is zero.

You should check if you received zero, and when that happens, you should clean up everything on the C++ side - the socket will no longer be usable.

If your design was for the client to keep waiting on this socket until it receives a new message, this is not possible once you close the output stream on the Java side. You should re-design your protocol so that Java does not close the stream (for example, if the server should send the client the number of bytes of the file in advance, the client could just read that exact number of bytes, and Java would not have to close the stream to let it know that the file is completed).

Comment: Thanks! Stupid Java closing the socket.. But I think That i tried not to close the outputstream, and then the c++ client didn't know when the file receiving was done. But I will try it anyway. Thanks for the time, this really helped me :)

Comment: As I said, you should redesign the protocol. If the client reads the file by looping until... it sees an end-of-file... then that will not work. If you first send a message saying "file is coming, it has 28005 bytes", and the client loops until it has read exactly 28005 bytes, it can stay alive.

Comment: Ok Now i get it! (finally) Thanks!